# Как создать обычный массив и положить туда асоциативный и как к нему потом обратиться?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как создать массив такого плана в с++ и как к нему потом обратиться!

на php знаю, на с++ не могу понять)

```
// код на php для примера
$ll = [
    1=>[
        'temp1' => 18,
        'temp2' => 19,
        'temp3' => 21,
    ],
    2=>[
        'temp1' => 12,
        'temp2' => 24,
        'temp3' => 36,
    ],
];
// обращаемся
$ll[1]['temp2'];
```

Comment: `std:array< std:map <string, int> , 2 >? `

Comment: А как его теперь заполнить? и потом к нему обратиться?

Comment: походу проще всего будет так + где то в комментах записать индексы к чему принадлежат. int b[ 2 ][ 2 ] = { 
  { 1, 2 }, 
  { 3, 4 },
  { 3, 4 }
  };

Answer (score 2):

В принципе просто

```
vector< map<string, int> > ll{
{{"temp1", 18}, {"temp2", 19}, {"temp3", 21}},
{{"temp1", 12}, {"temp2", 24}, {"temp3", 36}} };

// создание map
map<string, int> a;
a["temp1"] = 18;
a["temp2"] = 19;

// добавление в массив
ll.push_back(a);

// обращение
ll[0]["temp"] == 

// возвращаемые значения:
ll[0] - возвращает ссылку на 1 map в массиве, условно tmp
tmp["temp"] - возвращает ссылку на значение в map по ключу "temp"
```